# concurrent access to static TryParse methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I recently wrote a flat-file data profiler in C# - partly as just an interesting project. The profiler uses the various C# `TryParse` methods to determine data types.

Performance was poor and so I experimented with some different multi-threading approaches. (I had run the performance analyzer in Studio and it pointed to the parsing as a major chunk of the CPU time.)

I didn't see much improvement from threading and so I poked around the .Net code I could find on the web (`referencesource.microsoft.com`). The various parse methods are all static and appear to function in non-thread-safe manner.

Yet the threaded code produced the correct results. I didn't see any attributes that would have indicated thread synchronization in the .Net code. Which made me wonder if there was some synchronization mechanism that .Net was enforcing that I couldn't see in the code directly.

Does anyone know if the .Net runtime might be synchronizing access to the static parse methods somehow? That would explain

a) correct results with concurrent access to static methods and

b) no real performance improvement because the statics are a bottleneck.

I'm just puzzled.

UPDATED 32-Nov -- Here is a stripped-down version to illustrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace parse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalParseCount = 50000000;
            int maxThreads = 8;

            Console.WriteLine("TryParse\n--------");
            for (int threads = 1; threads <= maxThreads; ++threads)
            {
                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread count: {0}", threads));
                for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        int threadParseCount = 0;
                        while (threadParseCount < totalParseCount / threads)
                        {
                            int intOut;
                            long longOut;
                            DateTime dtOut;
                            decimal decOut;
                            int.TryParse("1b12i341i24b1234bo123", out intOut);
                            long.TryParse("1b12i341i24b1234bo123", out longOut);
                            DateTime.TryParse("1b12i341i24b1234bo123", out dtOut);
                            decimal.TryParse("1b12i341i24b1234bo123", out decOut);
                            ++threadParseCount;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("  Thread: {0}; Parse ops: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, threadParseCount));
                    }));
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): {0}", DateTime.Now - start));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and here is the output on my system (4 dual-core):

```
TryParse
--------
Thread count: 1
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 50000000
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:01:31.8389593
Thread count: 2
  Thread: 4; Parse ops: 25000000
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 25000000
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:00:58.8212779
Thread count: 3
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 16666666
  Thread: 4; Parse ops: 16666666
  Thread: 6; Parse ops: 16666666
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:00:47.8153264
Thread count: 4
  Thread: 6; Parse ops: 12500000
  Thread: 5; Parse ops: 12500000
  Thread: 4; Parse ops: 12500000
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 12500000
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:00:42.6872096
Thread count: 5
  Thread: 5; Parse ops: 10000000
  Thread: 6; Parse ops: 10000000
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 10000000
  Thread: 7; Parse ops: 10000000
  Thread: 4; Parse ops: 10000000
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:00:44.5965817
Thread count: 6
  Thread: 5; Parse ops: 8333333
  Thread: 6; Parse ops: 8333333
  Thread: 4; Parse ops: 8333333
  Thread: 8; Parse ops: 8333333
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 8333333
  Thread: 7; Parse ops: 8333333
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:00:41.9454271
Thread count: 7
  Thread: 9; Parse ops: 7142857
  Thread: 5; Parse ops: 7142857
  Thread: 6; Parse ops: 7142857
  Thread: 7; Parse ops: 7142857
  Thread: 4; Parse ops: 7142857
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 7142857
  Thread: 8; Parse ops: 7142857
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:00:40.8728885
Thread count: 8
  Thread: 10; Parse ops: 6250000
  Thread: 5; Parse ops: 6250000
  Thread: 9; Parse ops: 6250000
  Thread: 7; Parse ops: 6250000
  Thread: 6; Parse ops: 6250000
  Thread: 4; Parse ops: 6250000
  Thread: 8; Parse ops: 6250000
  Thread: 3; Parse ops: 6250000
Elapsed (HH:MM:SS.Milli): 00:00:37.8051313
```

There is an improvement but - certainly not close to linear with the increase in threads. I doubt there' a clear cut explanation - but I wanted to share the code since a couple folks took the time to respond. Thanks.

Comment: Static methods likely only use local variables and call other similar methods; they're are not affected by threading issues.

Comment: "appear to function in non-thread-safe manner" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Maybe you should post your code here or perhaps Code Review SE for us to determine why performance in your code is poor. Regards

Comment: Incidentally, using `TryParse` methods in succession to determine data types is not a good approach if you want performance, especially for complex stuff like `DateTime`, and it breaks down even more severely if different locales have to be considered. You're much better off compiling a collection of regexes from format string or using simple heuristics to categorize a string as "most probably this" before you even invoke any parse method.

Comment: I know that - I omitted the actual parsing logic because that wasn't the focus of the question. The focus of the question was the performance of TryParse across threads. By the way - do you know factually that regexes are more performant than TryParse?

Comment: As in, have I built something and tested it? No. But true regular expressions can always be combined into one and turned into a DFA with linear performance. Meaning that, irrespective of the number of types to check, you can recognize the type in time linear to the number of characters in your string, as opposed to (at least) the N times you'd invoke individual parsers. The trick is not whether individual regexes are faster or slower than particular `TryParse` methods (that will vary), but that recognizing all of them simultaneously is faster.

Comment: What were you expecting as the result?

Answer (score 1):

Threads are not free, they have overhead to use. The less work each thread has the more the ratio of work to overhead is.

Also unless your system has 8 cores having more threads than cores will not give any real benifits.